# Avoid an error from an undefined input-field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an input-field in my form which sometimes gets displayed and sometimes not. When the input-field doesn´t get displayed and the form is about to get sent the script throws an error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

I tried to catch that with this code:

```
if (typeof document.forms["add-new-job"].addjob_companyselect.value !== 'undefined') {
        // do something
}
```

But the same error comes again on this line. How can I skip an undefined field?

Comment: Maybe just check to see if it's defined first, before trying to extract its `.value`? (though this sounds like a bit of an X/Y problem)

Comment: You'll want to check the `typeof document.forms["add-new-job"].addjob_companyselect`, not its `.value`

Comment: Oh, thanks.. I feel stupid now :)

Comment: Check out this solution... [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700783/any-script-to-ignore-undefined-variable/46700934](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700783/any-script-to-ignore-undefined-variable/46700934)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var addNewJobElement = document.forms["add-new-job"].addjob_companyselect;
if (addNewJobElement && addNewJobElement.value) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: An input's `.value` is never `undefined`

Comment: Also, if the form doesn't exist yet, this will also throw.